# React Native : Alternate way to get the Image require to work when array of image paths got dynamically from fetchapi

Tags: react-native

React Native : Alternate way to get the Image require to work when array of image paths got dynamically from fetchapi

Tried the below and  aware that require always need the fixed path in quotes('') which works well when static image path is known. Thee should be alternate way to map the images which is received from fetchapi.

```
source={require('./assets/images/'+{item.image_path})} 
Example fetch api json response is: [{user_name: 'DynamicUser1', image_path: 'DynamicUser1.jpg'},{user_name: 'TestUser1', image_path: 'TestUser1.jpg'}... ]
```

Need alternate way to get the images rendered with the dynamic image path rightly picked from the fetch api.

```js
userData = this.state.resultsUserData.map((item) => {

    return (
              <View key={item.user_name} style={ styles.container }>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                  {item.user_name}
                </Text> 

        <TouchableOpacity goBack={()=>this.backAction} onPress={()=>this.homepage()}>
                  <Image key={item.image_path} 
                    source={require('./assets/images/'+{item.image_path})}
                </TouchableOpacity> 
        </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`require` doesn't work dynamically like that. Since you already have the images in the assets, you should write the `require`'s for each of them in advance and call the appropriate one when needed. You can read more about this limitation [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at it but could not get the way I need to overcome this static path issue. I have the images with filenames in assets/images folder. My fetchapi call will get an array of json objects like below with file name based on my query :[{user_name: 'DynamicUser1', image_path: 'DynamicUser1.jpg'},{user_name: 'TestUser1', image_path: 'TestUser1.jpg'}... ]. Need to know how to do the same. I have put the code above with this map function:userData = this.state.resultsUserData.map((item)